# Проблемы с методом collapseToStart в Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Сразу к делу, метод `collapseToStart` (и `End` тоже) не работают в Firefox (версия 37 -- последняя на сегодняшний день)

```js
function checkFor() {
  var el1 = document.getElementById("el1");

  var rng = document.createRange();
  rng.selectNodeContents(el1);

  var sel = window.getSelection();

  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(rng);

  sel.collapseToStart(); //Вот этот метод не работает в мозиле, версия 37
}
```

```html
<div id="el1" contenteditable>Текст внутри div</div>
<br>
<br>
<div onclick="checkFor();" style="padding:10px;">[Устанавливаем каретку]</div>
```

Кликните по ссылке в квадратных скобках -- фокус должен появиться перед словом "Текст". В Chrome все работает, в IE (в последней версии) -- тоже.

ВНИМАНИЕ!!!

Проблему решил следующий образом:
На блок установил фокус при помощи метода `focus()` и затем в Firefox все заработало. А именно: во вторую строчку функции `checkFor` добавил строчку `el1.focus()` и все.

P.S. Нужно было доки на mozilla.org читать, а я дурень)

Comment: Ответ на вопрос следует оформлять в виде Ответа ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос! Он побудил меня провести небольшое исследование.

Что происходит:

1. При нажатии вне `contenteditable` элемента фокусированный элемент ([document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)) по умолчанию меняется: в приведенном примере фокус перемещается на `<body>`.
2. При изменении `selection` (например, через метод `collapseToStart`), Chrome (и Safari) перемещают фокус на элемент, в котором оказалось выделение (selection). Firefox же этого не делает, отсюда и наблюдаемое поведение.

Исследование показывает, что в WebKit это поведение реализовано [с древних времен](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/241a3ce9483d674ec9660e874758dbea89006272%5E%21/WebCore/khtml/khtml_part.cpp) и без явных на то причин. В спецификациях это поведение не описано ([W3C 14383](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=14383)), и возможно, [поведение еще изменится](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38696).

Соответственно, вариантов решения может быть два:

- Ваш, где фокус принудительно возвращается в `contenteditable` и **после этого** устанавливается selection (отмечу, что сама по себе установка фокуса обратно "сбрасывает" selection в начало, как минимум в Firefox)
- Отмена поведения по умолчанию: для этого надо [ловить событие `mousedown` и выполнять в нем `event.preventDefault()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8736218/1026).

P.S. [Добавил эту информацию на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection#Selection_and_input_focus).